Monaco editor slow performance with large JSON schema
Does anyone know how I could improve the performance of Monaco Editor when using a large JSON schema file, provided via JS in the diagnostic options. If I provide the same JSON schema inside VS Code using the $schema key, the performance is unaffected. Are there any options I can configure?

Passing the schema in via $schema does not lead to slow performance, but passing it in via JS does. Using $schema is an acceptable workaround, but curious to know why this happens
